24.04 Python Selenium Firefox driver broken
I had a previously working python script (on 22.04) that uses the Selenium package with the Firefox driver.  Now it seems that the Python Selenium package can never find the Firefox Driver geckodriver, but it's possibly the driver location.
The cited error is:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for firefox using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

The Firefox driver is available, and in the path:
# which geckodriver
/snap/bin/geckodriver

At first I thought it was the snap at fault, but even copying geckogriver to /usr/bin did not make a difference.
I tried a bunch of driver options in python, including passing the path to the driver executable, etc. etc.  But none of these seemed to help.
Interestingly, the path cited in the error message does not actually exist:
# ls -la /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager': No such file or directory

And neither does the linux part of that, it only exists up to common.
On another machine, I installed Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch (rather than an upgrade), but hit exactly the same issue.

Would be a good idea to contact whom ever made that driver and find out if it is supposed to work with Ubuntu 24.04

@David - The "gecko" driver is part of the Ubuntu 24.04 Firefox Snap.  The Selenium module is from an Ubuntu .deb (AFAIK)   I just think the 24.04 Selenium package just doesn't work (or maybe they only tested it with chrome)

As a workaround, it's possible to specifically tell the webdriver where to find geckodriver ~
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# ...

opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
serv = webdriver.FirefoxService( executable_path='/snap/bin/geckodriver' )

# TODO - set some more options

ffox_driver = webdriver.Firefox( options=opts, service=serv )  
ffox_driver.get( some_url )

I don't know why this works, yet relocating geckodriver into the $PATH doesn't work.

This is an excellent answer with a working example. Thank you for adding it. It helped me a lot.
